# Check if a number is odd or even (mathematical parity)

Tags: assembly, x86-16, parity

For a one digit number, I want to know if it's odd or even (multiple of 2).  For example, given 9, print that is an odd number.

(i.e. check the [mathematical parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics)), not the computing [parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit).)

This is what I have:

```
   assume cs:cseg,ds:dseg,ss:sseg
    cseg segment
    start:  
    mov ax, dseg
    mov ds, ax  
    
    mov ah, 01h ; Here, im adding a number
    int 21h 
    
    
    
    jp even
    jnp odd  
    
    even: 
    mov ah,09
    lea dx,par
    int 21h  
    jmp exit
    odd: 
    mov ah,09
    lea dx,odd1 
    int 21h   
    jmp salir
    salir:
    mov ax,4C00h
    int 21h
    
    cseg ends 
    
    dseg segment byte         
    even Db 'Even number$'
    odd11 Db 'Odd number$'
    dseg ends  
    
    sseg segment stack
    db 100h dup(?)
    sseg ends

end start
```

Answer (score 6):

To test if a number is odd or even, **you check bit 0 of this number**. if bit0 is set, then the number is odd. nothing else.
Don't confuse PF (parity flag) and JP/JNP conditions. Parity Flag shows if the number of bits set in the least significant byte is even or odd.

From documentation:

> PF (bit 2) Parity flag — Set if the least-significant byte of the result contains an even number of 1 bits;
>   cleared otherwise.

Number 1 - odd number, 00000001b PF is cleared because there's only one bit set
Number 2 - even number, 00000010b, but PF is cleared again! because there's only one bit set
Number 3 - odd number, 00000011b, but PF set! because there're two bits set

Comment: @TheLogicGuy: `test eax, 1`

Comment: Or better, `test al, 1` because there's no `test r32, imm8` encoding, so it's shorter to only read the low byte of `eax` by reading `al`.  (Writing partial registers is bad, reading them is fine.)

Answer (score 4):

While Alexander Zhak's answer pointed out the flaws in your code checking the parity flag, the fastest way to check the parity of the number in al in a non-desctructive way is:

```
        test al,1
        jz even
odd:    ...
even:   ...
```

Answer (score 3):

To test if a number is odd or even, just shift it right once and check the carry flag:

```
    mov     al, 09
    shr     al       ; shifts all bits right 1, lowest bit to carry flag
    jc      _odd     ; carry set - there was a bit in lowest position
_even:
    ; Do something with even numbers and exit
_odd:
    ; Do something with odd numbers and exit
```

Understanding the carry flag is very useful for a whole variety of coding tricks. For instance, "Parity" is counting up the total number of bits in the number and we can use a similar trick for that:

```
    mov    ah, 09
    xor    al, al    ; al = 0
_loop:
    shr    ah        ; lower bit into carry flag
    adc    al, 0     ; Add 0 + carry flag to al
    and    ah, ah    ; sets Z flag if ah is zero
    bne    _loop
    ;  al now contains the total number of bits contained in ah
```

Comment: minus for "just shift it right once and check the carry flag" which destroys data which is being checked

Comment: He just wants to know whether it's odd or even, not re-use it. 1 instruction byte and no memory access overhead is the most efficient way of checking *if* you aren't going to use the value again (which he isn't in his code).

Comment: @Mike: `test al,1` / `jnz _odd` is *significantly* more efficient than a shift.  On Intel since Core2 and AMD since Bulldozer, that can macro-fuse into a single test-and-branch uop.  `shr al` and `test al,1` are both 2-byte instructions.  Your loop is also less efficient than it could be.  First `test ah,ah` would be better than `and`.  Second, you can arrange it so you branch on ZF as set by `shr`.  (e.g. with `adc al,0` / `shr ah` / `jnz _loop` / `adc al,0`.  On the first iteration, `adc al,0` is a no-op because the `xor al,al` cleared CF.  After exiting the loop, you add the last bit's CF.

Comment: See http://agner.org/optimize/ and other x86 performance links in the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Comment: @Mike: you claim that `shr al` is 1 instruction byte (which would be faster on 8088).  It's 2 bytes, same as `test al,1`; there is no special case AL / AX no-modrm encoding for shifts, only other instructions that actually take an immediate like `test`.  (Variable-count shifts were new in 186, and no short-form exists for them either, but if one did it would still be 2 total bytes.)

Comment: Also, the computing definition of parity is just whether the popcount is odd or even, not the actual total.  So `test al,al` / `jp`.  Or for the whole AX, `xor al,ah` / `jp`.  No need to do a popcount loop unless you actually want the total, and don't have the `popcnt` instruction available.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

Just add "and al,00000001" above of jp even

```
assume cs:cseg,ds:dseg,ss:sseg
    cseg segment
    start:  
    mov ax, dseg
    mov ds, ax  

    mov ah, 01h ; Here, im adding a number
    int 21h 

and al,00000001

    jp even
    jnp odd  

    even: 
    mov ah,09
    lea dx,par
    int 21h  
    jmp exit
    odd: 
    mov ah,09
    lea dx,odd1 
    int 21h   
    jmp salir
    salir:
    mov ax,4C00h
    int 21h

    cseg ends 

    dseg segment byte         
    even Db 'Even number$'
    odd11 Db 'Odd number$'
    dseg ends  

    sseg segment stack
    db 100h dup(?)
    sseg ends

end start
```

Comment: 1 - 0000_0001 an odd number, parity odd. 2 - 0000_0010 an even number, parity odd. 3 - 0000_0011 an odd number, parity even. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Better: `test al, 1` instead of `and al,1`.  Same instruction length, but can macro-fuse with `jcc` on modern CPUs.  (Even `jp`, although the parity of a single bit is the same as testing whether it's zero, which would be easier to understand and just as fast, although this does work.)

Answer (score -1):

```
    .MODEL SMALL
 .STACK 100H

 .DATA
   PROMPT_1  DB  'Enter a number: $'
   PROMPT_2  DB  0DH,0AH,'The given number in binary is: $'
   PROMPT_3  DB  0DH,0AH,'$' 
   MSG1 DB 10,13,’Number is Odd $’
   MSG2 DB 10,13,’Number is Even $’

 .CODE
   MAIN PROC
     MOV AX, @DATA                
     MOV DS, AX

     LEA DX, PROMPT_1                
     MOV AH, 9
     INT 21H

     XOR BL, BL                  
     MOV CX, 8                   
     MOV AH, 1                   

     @INPUT:                     
       INT 21H                   
       CMP AL, 0DH                
       JE @END                   
       AND AL, 0FH                
       SHL BL, 4                 
       OR BL, AL                  
     LOOP @INPUT                  

     @END:                        

     MOV AL, BL                   
     MOV CX, 8                    

     @LOOP:                       
       SHR AL, 1                  
       RCL BL, 0                  
     LOOP @LOOP                   

     LEA DX, PROMPT_2             
     MOV AH, 9
     INT 21H

     MOV CX, 8                    
     MOV AH, 2                    

     @OUTPUT:                     
       SHL BL, 1                  

       JNC @ZERO                  
         MOV DL, 31H              
         JMP @DISPLAY             

       @ZERO:                     
         MOV DL, 30H              

       @DISPLAY:                  
         INT 21H                  
     LOOP @OUTPUT                      



MOV AH,01H
INT 21H 

mov ah,01h


SAR AL,01h
JC ODD


LEA SI,MSG1
CALL PRINT

JMP TERMINATE

ODD:
LEA SI,MSG2
CALL PRINT


TERMINATE:
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H

PRINT PROC
MOV DX,SI
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H




     MOV AH, 4CH                 
     INT 21H

 END MAIN
```

Comment: What does this do, and why is it a useful answer to this question?  Is `shr al,1` / `rcl bl, 0` / `loop` supposed to bit-reverse AL?  It doesn't; [`rcl`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/RCL:RCR:ROL:ROR.html) with a count of zero is an expensive no-op, and isn't supported on 8086.  `rcl bl, 1` works on 8086, and would make a correct bit-reverse loop.  Anyway, you only need to look at the last decimal digit of a multi-digit number to decide if it's odd or even, so you're way overcomplicating this (whatever this is...)